# Always get before all" hook for in test and can't fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sinon, stub

```
before(function (func: (...args: any[]) => any) {
  app = express();

  // prepare environment
  sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

  // stub
  sandbox.stub(app, "post").callsFake(() => {
    return Promise.resolve("send a post");
  });

  ingestEventStub = sandbox.stub(IngestController.prototype, "ingestEvent").callsFake(function () {
    return Promise.resolve({
      success: true,
      message: "anymessage"
    });
  });

  eventRoutesV1 = EventRoutesV1(app, express);
  ingestController = new IngestController();
});

beforeEach(function () {
  sandbox.resetHistory();
});

afterEach(function () {
  sandbox.restore();
});


it('should send 200 back and pubsub message when call /event ', function (done) {

  const httpBody = {
    "id": "id",
    "version": "version",
    "creationTime": "creationTime",
    "environment": "environment",
    "name": "name",
    "tenantId": "tenantId",
    "payloadType": "payloadType",
    "payloadVersion": "payloadVersion",
    "payload": {}
  };

  request(app)
    .post('/event/ingestEvent')
    .send(httpBody)
    .end((err, res) => {
      expect(res.body).to.equal({ success: true });
      expect(res.status).to.equal(HTTP_STATUS_CODES.OK);
      done();
    }).then(done, done)
});
```

The error:

```
1) "before all" hook for "should send 200 back and pubsub message when call /event "

Error: Timeout of 50000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. 
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

I don't know why it always get this error and I can't find the premise that unresolved

Answer (score 3):

The function passed to `before` includes a parameter called `func`.

If the function passed to `before` includes a parameter, it is assumed to be a `done` parameter.

Since `func` (treated as a `done` parameter) is never called, the test times out in the `before` hook.

It looks like you don't need a `done` parameter in your `before` callback so just remove `func` and that will keep the test from timing out:

```
before(function () {  // <= remove "func"
    app = express();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. you save my world. That's solves the issue.

Comment: Glad it's working now!  Also, friendly reminder to click the checkmark next to the answer to mark the answer as accepted, thx!  @HanGao